# how to resolve FutureError Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is my code

```
    x = df.groupby([targetFeature])
    for name, group in x:
        # do stuff
```

I keep getting this error:

FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas, a length 1 tuple will be returned when iterating over a groupby with a grouper equal to a list of length 1. Don't supply a list with a single grouper to avoid this warning.

How do I resolve this warning?

Comment: `FutureWarning` is **not** an error, but a warning.